# How can I keep the app instance web api net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I use start/stop buttons on the UI side, And I have these methods on the Web Api.
The program starts when UI calls the start method web Api .Now the UI wants to stop the current instance 
but the controller  web Api create new instance :)
How can I keep the app instance؟

here is my Api code:

```
namespace Example.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IService _service;

        public ValuesController()
        { }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Start(Data data)
        {
            _service = ServiceFactory.GetAppService();
            _service.Start();
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Stop()
        {
            _service.Stop();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean: "How do you stop another `ValuesController` being made so you can keep control over the *same* `IService` instance?"

Comment: New controller instance created for every request - you will not change it, but you can register `IService` as singleton, so same instance of service will be used for all controller instances.

Comment: @Fabio An instance of the controller must be created whenever a start is made and passing the same to the stop in next request

Comment: @mohammadalmasi did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single instance of `IService` that will share between requests, then you can register `IService` as a singleton.

To do that add this code to Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IService>(s = ServiceFactory.GetAppService());
```

then, this code to the constructor of `ValuesController`

```
public ValuesController(IService service)
{
    _service = service;
}
```

and remove this line

```
_service = ServiceFactory.GetAppService();
```